# Enabling Classic Long Click Behavior On Windows 8.1 Tablets

Tags: windows-8, tablet, touchscreen, accessibility

I have several programs installed on a new Windows 8.1 tablet, that require a long left-mouse button press to perform certain actions. The problem is, I can't seem to mimic this functionality when using the touchscreen. I've gone to the "Pen and Touch" settings to disable the "press and hold for right click" feature, but this doesn't result in classic behavior being restored. Is there anyway around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of programs are these that differentiate between short and long left clicks?

Comment: Poorly thought-out corporate software... :)